# Access to Mobile Contact of user through website

Tags: html, android-contacts, google-contacts-api

Is it possible to access mobile phone contacts/google contacts through a mobile/desktop website.

I am okay with the access being similar to playstore app where a user first have to allow the website to access contacts

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can access Google's [`People APIs`](https://developers.google.com/people/).

To easily get permission and do authentication on behalf of the user to those APIs, you can use `Google Play Services` `GoogleAPI` service, see [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client) and [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth).

Comment: Thanks Marmor, is it possible to access phone numbers using android platform similar to how apps do. (for cases where user have not synced their contact details on google)

Comment: no, the Android APIs are governed by the Android permissions system, which is for apps only, the browser is just yet another app on Android, and has its set of permissions like any other app, it can't provide websites a permission it doesn't have.
However, you can pretty easily wrap your website in a simple wrapper Android app, release it to Google Play, and allow your website to be visited as an app. Then you could take advantage of Android's Contacts APIs.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marmor